# Function that prints a different value than it returns

Tags: function-construction

I want to create a function something like this:

`test[x_] := (Print[1]; Return[2];)`

Except it prints `1` when executed as `test[a]` for any `a` on the notebook, but when used in computations uses the `2` value instead.

Thus `test[2342]` will output just `1` but `test[43589] + 1` will output just `2` (because the value returned, 2, is used instead).

I have looked into `Interpretation` but that returns a held object and does not allow you do perform operations like `test[1] + 123` without explicitly releasing the hold.

Comment: `test[1]+1` prints `1` and outputs `3`

Comment: @eldo I know. I only want it to output 3, and hide the 1. However, if you just call `test[1]` then I want it to print `1` and hide the `2`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Does this do what you're after?

```
ClearAll[test];
test[a_] /; Length[Stack[]] == 3 := 1
test[a_] := 2

test[134123]
(* 1 *)

Identity[test[134123]]
(* 2 *)

1 + test[134123]
(* 3 *)
```

The value return by [`Stack[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Stack.html) in the condition is in the first example

```
{test, Equal, Length}
```

In the second, it is

```
{Identity, test, Equal, Length}
```

One can see that if `test` is called by itself, the length of the stack will be three.  If `test` appears inside other functions, the stack will be longer.

Comment: I seem to recall a similar question a few weeks ago, but I can't find it. Anyone?

Comment: Yes! Just what I needed!

Comment: +1 - there's a function not seen often!

Comment: @rasher Yes, and with good reason, I expect.  Thanks for the upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
ClearAll[test]
test[1] := Print[1]
test[x_] := Return[2]

test[1]
```

`1`

```
test[2] + 1
```

`3`

Comment: I think I chose a bad example. In general just entering `test[a]` should give `1` but using `test[a]` in any computation should use the value `2`

Answer (score 0):

```
test[x_, code_] := If[code == 1, Print[1], 2]

    test[anything,1]
(*1*)

    test[anything,2]
(*2*)
```